# Find path to file on server using php -

Tags: php, filepath, absolute-path

I would like to know how to get the absolute file path of the file i have found using `glob()` function. I am able to find a desired file using

```
foreach (glob("access.php") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename absolutepath is:  ";
}
```

not sure what function gets the full path of the file searched. Tried to google but can't find anything sensible.

Thanks

Slight update : 
I have noticed that glob() function only searches the directory that the script is run from - and that is not good to me. I need a function that is equivalent to unix `find / -name "somename"`

Any alternative ? or am i missing something with the glob() ??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have to look also for files in subdirectories, you could use something like the following:

```
foreach (glob("{access.php,{*/,*/*/,*/*/*/}access.php}", GLOB_BRACE) as $filename) {
    echo "$filename absolutepath is:  ".realpath($filename);
}
```

Comment: unfortunately this still does not give me what i want. ?i.e to test this i have placed a .txt file somewhere on the filesystem - and this function did not find it - Note :  that the file name has a unique name so there is no 2nd file with same name on FS

Comment: It only searches for the given file in the script file directory or sub-directory. What i need is a function that searches whole file system

Answer (score 0):

You can use realpath to get file absolute path. More info: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

Answer (score 0):

I thinkt you need realpath(), as described here: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.realpath.php

```
foreach (glob("access.php") as $filename) {
    echo "$filename absolutepath is:  " . realpath($filename);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The directory in which the glob function searches is available through the getcwd function.

To search any directory, given its path, one may use the following code snippet:

```
$dirToList       = '/home/username/documents';
$patternToSearch = '*.odt'; // e.g. search for LibreOffice OpenDocument files
$foundFiles      = FALSE;
$olddir          = getcwd();
if (chdir($dirToList)) {
    $foundFiles = glob($patternToSearch);
    chdir($olddir); // switch back to the dir the code was running in before
    if ($foundFiles) {
        foreach ($foundFiles as $filename) {
            echo nl2br(htmlentities(
                 'found file: '.$dirToList.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$filename."\n"
                  , ENT_COMPAT, 'UTF-8'));
         }
     }
     // else echo 'no found files';
 }
 // else echo 'chdir error';
```

To finally satiesfy your wish to do a search like

> find / -name "somename"

you may put that code snippet in a function and call it while iterating through the directory tree of interest using PHP's [RecursiveDirectoryIterator](http://php.net/manual/de/class.recursivedirectoryiterator.php) class.